# Understanding Communication diagram

Tags: uml, class-diagram, sequence-diagram

Consider the following diagrams:
[image]

I want to transform these diagrams into JAVA code, but i find it difficult to figure the communication diagram. I searched a lot in the web but couldn't find something that explain the flow of it(how to literally read it), just "what the meaning of it".

So far, from the class diagram ,i know that class B is a sub-class of A, and B and C knowing each other (and also each one of them have a private member of the other), but, what the meaning of the arrows and the index ? Class B call op3 of its own c? but when, why, how?

Comment: this is not a java question go read your professor's notes

Comment: You should also point out to your professor that the dotted arrow shown on the class diagram is not UML. I'm assuming that he wanted to use a dependency, but a dependency in UML cannot be bi-directional, and the notation for the arrowhead is slightly different. It should be an open arrowhead a bit like this: `--->`

Answer (score 1):

Follow the numbers:

1. Create instance of class `B` (which then becomes `:B`)
2. `:B` creates a new instance of `C`
3. `:B` calls the method `op3()` in `:C`

   1. `:C` calls `op2()` in `:B`

      1. `:B` calls `op1()` (from superclass `A`) in itself

Comment: This answer i like apart from the fact that B changed its name halfway.

Comment: @ChrisReynolds You need to read the first sentence as instance of `class B` which is then `B:`. I'll change that.

Comment: Thomas, I think your `:A` instances should be replace by `:B` instances. There are only two instances involved here, and you can of course perfectly call operations defined on the superclass `A` on the instance of the subclass `B` `:B`

Comment: @GeertBellekens ugh. You are right. Thanks for pointing it out :-)